# Why can't I import from js file?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Im using svg.js(v3.0.10, which is just "svg.draggable.js" needs) and svg.draggable.js, but I got an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './svg.js' does not provide an export named 'Box' (at svg.draggable.js:1:10)

My files is like:

```
html
→main.html
js
→api
 →svg.js
 →svg.draggable.js
```

the main.html is like:

```
<script src="./js/api/svg.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="./js/api/svg.draggable.js"></script>
```

I changed the "svg.draggable.js" like:

```
import { Box, Element, G, extend, off, on } from './svg.js'
```

And now I have no idea about why the error happened, I searched some similar questions but no one like what is happening to me. How can I fix it? Any suggestion is welcome !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to export everything you need :

```js
export { Box, Element, G, extend, off, on }
```

in the svg.js file.

Right now you are trying to import from svg.js but this file does not seems to export anything.

Edit :

i assumed svg.js was one of your files and that you were able to modify it, but i now understand it's not the case,

Since you include svg.js with a script there should be a window.SVG defined in the browser and you could use that instead.

The file you are trying to import does not contain any export because it's meant to be used by the browser, so you can remove the import and keep the script in your html.

If you want to import the esm module instead, you will need to delete the svg.js and get the esm version instead, for example this one :
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/3.2.0/svg.esm.min.js

i would suggest installing it using npm/yarn, it's way better than copy pasting files into your project

Comment: You are right, and I go do as what you said but a new error coming out like: `Export 'Box' is not defined in module` How can this happen? Is it wrong of svg.js? How it not be used by an API on its own page? Or did it's my wrong because of some stupid mistake?

Comment: @Tian_Godgiven i made an edit, i think you need to use the SVG property in the browser

Comment: Thank you so much , now i understanded what my really question is "what is esm and how to use it" . Im so confused before because i completely dont know it. Appreciate to your knowledge and patient !

Comment: Well i think you will need to dive into modules, because there is a lot of different types of modules : amd,umd, esm an so on, you could start with this article : https://dev.to/iggredible/what-the-heck-are-cjs-amd-umd-and-esm-ikm

Comment: Also i made a small error in my edit, i said that your svg.js file was a commonjs module, it's not the case, that file is not a module at all, but just a plain javascript file

Comment: Thank you ! This is exactly what i need! I learn c++ before so i can understand how import it is to reduce file coupling, and this is greatly helpful to me!